# Is there a scratch pad app that syncs?

Tags: sync

I use Google scratch pad app in my Google Desktop on my laptop. It is no longer available from Google.  I am looking for a similar app that will sync between my laptop and my phone.  Does anyone know of such an app?  Thanks-

Comment: What does the application do?

Comment: This seems like a product recomendation.  Evernote and One Note the top two contenders in this arena.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's One Note is criminally underrated and yes it's now cloud based. Check it out.

[image: One Note]

Answer (score 1):

[Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep) - Quickly capture what’s on your mind and be reminded at the right place or time. Create a checklist, enter a voice note or snap a photo and annotate it. Everything you add is instantly available on all your devices – **desktop** and **mobile**.

With Google Keep you can:

- Keep track of your thoughts via notes, lists and photos
- Add reminders to important notes and be reminded through Google Now
- Have voice notes transcribed automatically
- Use widgets to capture thoughts quickly
- Color-code your notes to help find them later
- Swipe to archive things you no longer need
- Turn a note into a checklist by adding checkboxes
- Use your notes from anywhere - they are safely stored in the cloud and available on the web at https://keep.google.com and via the Google Keep app in the Chrome Web Store.

<sup>**Source:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep</sup>

Comment: Keep is the official replacement for Scratchpad. It even works on Chromebooks.